# Why am I getting a value of zero for my circle?

Tags: c#, geometry, area

Here is my Circle class code.

```
class Circle
{
    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double Area
    {
        set { area = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); }
        get { return area; }

    }
}
```

This is test code.

```
    Circle circle1 = new Circle(3);

    MessageBox.Show("Circle 1 Area: " + circle1.Area);
```

So for some reason, when I use the MessageBox.Show(), it seems to give me values of zero instead. I gave the circle a value of 3 so shouldn't my constructor set the value of the radius that?

Comment: I think this is because you don't compute the area when you call "circle1.Area". You put the computation in the "set" instead of the "get".

Comment: Always best to store the bare minimum and derive related quantities on demand. Caching as you do here makes you vulnerable to errors. As you discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you haven't ever called the setter on Area. Perhaps you want something like this instead?

```
class Circle
{
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double Area
    {
        get { return Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); }    
    }
}
```

This will compute the Area every time it is requested.

Comment: Also, if I want to create an array for 3 circles, how do I do that? just curious. I only know the very basics of an array for primitive types.

Answer (score 6):

Your `Area` property should be:

```
public double Area
{
    get { return Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); }
}
```

and you don't need the `area` field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need a `set` in this instance (You didn't use it)

try

```
    get { return  Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2); }
```