# Point Structure in derived classes

Tags: shapes

Can someone clarify how to use the existing point structure, in derived classes?

Comment: Please add the homework tag if this is homework.

Comment: So, what do you have so far?

Comment: Just a flowchart, as I said, I don't really understand the challenge. Can someone explain it to me, or show me how to begin coding it using the Point Structure? I don't need a complete answer, I just need help starting it.

Comment: You want us to do your homework? Please put some effort into it and don't just copy stuff from the net. If this is out of your league try to address your instructor. I'm sure the material needed for doing this has been covered in your class

Comment: You just have to implement what's written in the task. That's the short answer.

Comment: AZ, this is not homework, it is from a Programming Book, I am trying to learn it by myself and do all exercises before moving on to the next Chapter. Yes, it is out of my league, which is why am I asking your help (not to do the exercise for me, but to just clarify the question). If it is out of your league as well, there is no need to be demeaning. Thanks!

Comment: Homework or not it doesn't matter. You don't have a specific problem,you need an entire program and this site isn't appropriate place for this.These kinds of questions are off-topic in SO

Comment: If it's from a book and you don't understand it, maybe you should go back and re-read the prior chapters?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19844974/2804613 If you want the Circle. Next time please show some code to start off so you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want a starting point, here's how to start the task (or pretty much anything similar; this is just how I'd do it, there are multiple approaches):

The existing point structure mentioned is `System.Drawing.Point`. So you'll most likely want to use a `using` directive to make your code shorter and more readable:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Now to start with the first point:

> The Shape class has a single property named Name, a constructor with a Name parameter, and a MustOverride method named GetArea that returns a Double. It has a ToString method that returns the name of the shape.

This is pretty long, so let's break it down:

- The class is called *Shape*.
- There is a property *Name*.
- The constructor has a parameter *Name*.
- There is an unimplemented method *GetArea* returning a `double` value (-> this is going to be an `abstract` class).
- There is a method *ToString* returning the name.

If it's easier for you, write down such details on a sheet of paper. It can help you a lot when trying to get started. Then try to do this step by step:

> - The class is called *Shape*.

Let's start with the basic class definition:

```
public class Shape {

}
```

So this point is done already. The next task:

> - There is a property *Name*.

This is a bit more complicated and there are several ways to do this. Considering there's also an accessor for this (see later step), I don't think it's a real property and just a member variable instead (if you disagree, see the end of my answer). The data type isn't named, but since we want it to be a short word, we'll use `string`. So let's add it:

```
public class Shape {
    private string Name;
}
```

Now we're going to need the constructor:

> - The constructor has a parameter *Name*.

This is again quite trivial. This is where we set the `Name` we've just defined:

```
public class Shape {
    private string Name;

    public Shape(string Name) {
        this.Name = Name; // The use of 'this' is required, since both names overlap.
    }
}
```

Since the constructor has to be accessible from the outside, we define it as `public`. The next step is a bit tricky:

> - There is an unimplemented method *GetArea* returning a `double` value (-> this is going to be an `abstract` class).

So let's break it down first. We'll need a method *GetArea* that we won't implement here. Due to this, the class has to be made `abstract` using the keyword of the same name. That means that not all members are implemented already, but derived classes will have to implement them on their own. So we add the new member method's signature (= no function body) as well as the keyword:

```
public abstract class Shape { // this 'abstract' tells the compiler that this class can't be instantiated
    private string Name;

    public Shape(string Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public abstract double GetArea(); // this 'abstract' forces derived classes to implement this method
}
```

If you're not sure what the keyword `abstract` does, read it up again. While there are ways around using it, it makes things a lot easier and more elegant. Now there's only one simple last step left:

> - There is a method *ToString* returning the name.

Once again, this is trivial to add. There's again no data type named, but since we plan on returning a `string`, that's again easy to tell:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    private string Name;

    public Shape(string Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public abstract double GetArea();

    public override string ToString() { // The 'override' keyword here is important since you want this to replace the default method of the same name.
        return Name;
    }
}
```

That's it. You've got your base class ready. To create a derived class, all you have to do is name the base class, then add new members. Here's the barebone for the next class:

```
public class Rectangle : Shape {
    // ...
}
```

---

If you think the *Name* property is indeed meant to be a property, you could implement it like this:

```
public class Shape {
    private string name; // this is the actual variable behind the scenes.

    // this is a getter/setter accessing the 'name' string
    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;  }
    }
}
```

The same change applies to the other steps, but that's it.

Comment: Nice job @Mario, you're so patient.

Comment: +1 for this. As for the TS, he/she should consider himself lucky that he/she is getting this. Normally these type of questions won't go anywhere lol.

Comment: Thanks @ Mario, for understanding my question. I was not looking for a complete program, but an explanation of what the challenge is asking. You explained each task so well, much better than the book!

Answer (score 2):

OK, although these kind of questions are not so welcome in stackoverflow, I'll provide the classes for you and leave the instantiation business up to you:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public abstract double GetArea();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public Rectangle(Point upperLeft, Point lowerRight)
        : base("Rectangle")
    {
        this.upperLeft = upperLeft;
        this.lowerRight = lowerRight;
    }

    private Point upperLeft;
    private Point lowerRight;

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return (lowerRight.X - upperLeft.X) * (upperLeft.Y - lowerRight.Y);
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(Point center, double radius)
        : base("Circle")
    {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    private Point center;
    private double radius;

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2);
    }
}
```